# Dot product of rows in 2 matrices

Tags: python, numpy

So I basically have matrices

```
a = [x1,y1,z1
     x2,y2 z2
     .....
     xN,yN,zN]
```

and `b = [i1,j1,k1
         i2,j2,k2
          ....]`

and want to take the dot product of row 1 of a with row 1 of b, row 2 of a with row 2 of b and so on. They are both shape (3,71216) but

```
np.dot(a,b)
```

gives ValueError: objects are not aligned.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are they matrices or ndarrays?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want `np.tensordot`, though `einsum` will be easier to understand at that point.

Comment: Just to illustrate using `einsum`, you can do this with `np.einsum('ij,ij->j', a, b)`.  However, @wim's suggestion of using `sum` is arguably more readable for folks not used to Einstein summation notation.

Comment: `einsum` is 3x faster than `sum` on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `np.dot` is expecting the number of rows of the first argument to equal the number of columns of the second, as the error message suggests.

You will need align the arrays:

```
np.dot(a, b.T)
```

---

Your question is confusing because you say the arrays have shape (3, 71216), but your examples show the transpose (71216, 3).

Anyway, it sounds like you just want this, not a dot product:

```
(a * b).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: that gives me something with shape (3,3), but I need it to be (71216), essentially one result for every row in the array

Comment: @user3361147 you want a string of shape (71216,)? or actually (3,)?

Comment: Yeah that's it, thanks. I ballsed up with the way round I wrote the arrays in the question